# What is the right way to get unit vector to index Elasticsearch ann dot_product?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nlp

I am trying to index word embedding vectors to Elasticsearch V8 ann `dense_vector` `dot_product`.

I can successfully index `vec` to `cosine`, so I converted it to unit vector with numpy for `dot_product`.

```
    unit_vector = vec / np.linalg.norm(vec)
```

but I get an 400 error saying like this.

```
The [dot_product] similarity can only be used with unit-length vectors. Preview of invalid vector: [-0.0038341882, -0.1564709, 0.08771773, -0.14555556, -0.07952896, ...]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was confronted with the exact same problem and I found a solution after much experimentation.

In my case, when indexing lots of embeddings to Elasticsearch (dense_vector with similarity parameter set to dot_product), most of them got indexed properly and a small percentage of them failed with `The [dot_product] similarity can only be used with unit-length vectors.`

I found after intensive testing that the problem was that the unit vectors I was working with were of numerical types [np.float16](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.float16) and this was causing the error. Working with `np.float32` as a numerical type in my workflow for my unit vectors solved the issue.

Comment: I see. But I decided to use Qdrant instead. Thanks anyway.